# Raspbian OS in Windows7

Tags: raspbian, windows, virtualization

I want to practice Raspbian OS in my windows system(Windows 7 64-bit). Please suggest best and safe application

Comment: windows 7 64 bit is an *operating system* for an amd64 instruction set (intel or amd cpu) ... raspbian is also an *operating system* but for an arm6/7 cpu ... so the options are very limited - search for "raspberry pi emulation windows QEMU" and you'll find what you probably want

Comment: you can also use "raspbian for desktop" either as a bootable "live disc", or inside a virtual machine in windows, or even replace windows altogether (this last option is probably not what you want)

Comment: Of course you may want to convert your Windows PC to dual boot a Linux distribution - Debian is, by definition the most comparable to Raspbian as the latter is derived from it, and from the command line things will look very similar. As it happens I am using such an arrangement (well I triple boot FreeBSD but that isn't relevant here) myself - though I do have to take care that when working in a terminal window that I know whether I have `ssh`-ed into the RPi or not...!

Answer (score 1):

Get Oracle Virtualbox (it's a free download from https://www.virtualbox.org/) get Debian Stretch X86 (32-bit) from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/ and boot that in a Virtualbox.

Comment: You can use the Raspberry Pi Desktop, linked to by Dougie, to make a bootable USB pen drive, and if you enable persistent storage, you have an experience very much like a Raspberry Pi running from flash.

Comment: Do you feel that it's worth mentioning that Debian Stretch X86 is not exactly the same thing as Raspbian? I think your answer is a good one, but perhaps in a somewhat limited context, and/or it might confuse the point that Raspbian's ARM code can't be emulated under VirtualBox.

Comment: No, because to the naïve user it's virtually indistinguishable from Raspbian on a RPi.